# What is the "with" operator for in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, expression, keyword, c#-9.0

I've came across this code:

```
var rectangle = new Rectangle(420, 69);
var newOne = rectangle with { Width = 420 }
```

I was wondering about `with` keyword in C# code. What is it for? And how can it be used? And what benefits does it bring to the language?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's an operator used in expressions for easier duplication of an object, overriding some of it's public properties/fields (optional)
[with expression - MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/with-expression)

Currently it can only be used with records. But maybe there will be no such restriction in the future (assumption).

Here's an example how it can be used:

```
// Declaring a record with a public property and a private field
record WithOperatorTest
{
    private int _myPrivateField;

    public int MyProperty { get; set; }

    public void SetMyPrivateField(int a = 5)
    {
        _myPrivateField = a;
    }
}
```

Now let's see how `with` operator can be used:

```
var firstInstance = new WithOperatorTest
{
    MyProperty = 10
};
firstInstance.SetMyPrivateField(11);
var copiedInstance = firstInstance with { };
// now "copiedInstance" also has "MyProperty" set to 10 and "_myPrivateField" set to 11.

var thirdCopiedInstance = copiedInstance with { MyProperty = 100 };
// now "thirdCopiedInstance " also has "MyProperty" set to 100 and "_myPrivateField" set to 11.

thirdCopiedInstance.SetMyPrivateField(-1);
// now "thirdCopiedInstance " also has "MyProperty" set to 100 and "_myPrivateField" set to -1.
```

**NOTE for reference types from MSDN:**

> In the case of a reference-type member, only the reference to a member instance is copied when an operand is copied. Both the copy and original operand have access to the same reference-type instance.

That logic can be modified by modifying the copy constructor of a record type. Quote from MSDN:

> By default, the copy constructor is implicit, that is, compiler-generated. If you need to customize the record copy semantics, explicitly declare a copy constructor with the desired behavior.

```
protected WithOperatorTest(WithOperatorTest original)
{
   // Logic to copy reference types with new reference
}
```

And in terms of what benefits it gives, I think it should be quite obvious now, that it makes copying of instances much easier and convenient.

Answer (score 11):

In essence, when you use the `with` operator, it creates a new object instance, currently only for records. This new object instance is created by copying values from a source object and overriding specific named properties in the destination object.

For example, instead of doing this:

```
var person = new Person("John", "Doe")
{
    MiddleName = "Patrick"
};
 
var modifiedPerson = new Person(person.FirstName, person.LastName)
{
    MiddleName = "William"
};
```

you can do this:

```
var modifiedPerson = person with
{
    MiddleName = "Patrick"
};
```

Basically, you will write less code.

Use [this source](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/simpler-code-with-csharp-9) to get more details on the example above and [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/with-expression) for more examples.

Comment: Nice summary! Upvoted :) 
Except I'd recommend to make a minor improvement. I don't think this is a correct/clear statement: *override some named properties in the destination object*. What you mean by named properties?

Comment: @DavidOganov thank you! English is not my native language and that's why I have issues sometimes describing what I thought. By **named properties** I meant properties that you explicitly name in the record body to be overridden/changed. In my answer above, the named property will be `MiddleName` since that property I want to override/change.

Comment: Sure, np. Okay, I got it. Just note, that you can override all the public editable properties and **fields**.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is the following:
`with` keyword in C# was added for easier copy of complicated objects, with a possibility to override some of the public properties.
Examples are already briefly provided in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

A **[with expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/with-expression)** produces a ***copy of its operand*** with the specified properties and fields modified.

Starting with C# 10, the LHS operand of a **with** expression can now be - **records**, **structs** or **anonymous** types.

**Records**:

```
public record Person(string FirstName, string LastName);

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Person person = new("Nancy", "Davolio");
        Console.WriteLine(person);
        // output: Person { FirstName = Nancy, LastName = Davolio }
        
        var personCreatedUsingWithExpression = person with { FirstName = "Dave" };
        Console.WriteLine(personCreatedUsingWithExpression);
        // output: Person { FirstName = Dave, LastName = Davolio }
    }

}
```

**Records containing reference type member**: Only the reference to a member instance is copied when an operand is copied. Both the copy and original operand have access to the same reference-type instance.

> ```
> public class ExampleWithReferenceType {
>     public record TaggedNumber(int Number, List<string> Tags)
>     {
>         public string PrintTags() => string.Join(", ", Tags);
>     }
>
>     public static void Main()
>     {
>         var original = new TaggedNumber(1, new List<string> { "A", "B" });
>
>         var copy = original with { Number = 2 };
>         Console.WriteLine($"Tags of {nameof(copy)}: {copy.PrintTags()}");
>         // output: Tags of copy: A, B
>
>         original.Tags.Add("C");
>         Console.WriteLine($"Tags of {nameof(copy)}: {copy.PrintTags()}");
>         // output: Tags of copy: A, B, C
>      }
> }
> ```

**Structs**: Since a `record` in C# is technically a `struct`, it is easier to remember that `with` expression works with `struct`s as well.

```
public readonly struct Coords
{
    public Coords(double x, double y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public double X { get; init; }
    public double Y { get; init; }

    public override string ToString() => $"({X}, {Y})";
}

public static void Main()
{
    var p1 = new Coords(0, 0);
    Console.WriteLine(p1);  // output: (0, 0)

    var p2 = p1 with { X = 3 };
    Console.WriteLine(p2);  // output: (3, 0)

    var p3 = p1 with { X = 1, Y = 4 };
    Console.WriteLine(p3);  // output: (1, 4)
}
```

**Anonymous Types**:

```
var apple = new { Item = "apples", Price = 1.35 };
var onSale = apple with { Price = 0.79 };
```